# Encapsulating the sendAsync method of DelegatingHandler in an async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

I am working on a `DelegatingHandler` to intercept all the calls from one service to another. And I am totally new to `DelegatingHandlers`.

This is the issue. 
We currently have an API that takes calls and measure the concurrent calls and it has some mechanisms to throttle it if needed. it is in this form. (Since actual API is heavy for debugging I am actually using following stub methods to test this)

```
private  Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync1(Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> action)
{
    return ExecuteAsync2(action);
}

private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync2(Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> action)
{
    return await action().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Now within this Delegating handler I have to use this API like this.

```
protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (this.ThrottlingFactory == null || !this.ThrottlingEnabled)
    {
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
    else
    {
        var response = await this.ExecuteAsync1(() =>
        {
            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        });

        // Analyse response for certain thing here.

        return response;
    }
}
```

My problem is, after executing ExecuteAsync1 (it actually completes the ExecuteAsync2) the code never return back. I tried numerous variation of this like adding async/await to all the methods in the chain including the anon method etc. non worked. So can somebody please point me to things I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Not sure if it'll make a difference, but you can remove the `async`/`await` keywords from `ExecuteAsync2`. Other than that, I don't see any obvious issues. Can you provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please?

Comment: Thanks @dcastro. I cant change the signature of the `ExecuteAsync2` as it has to actually get the result and work on it and I don't own it. This is part of a large project and I will try to provide MCVE for this.

Comment: @Herne: Is this the exact code that you see this behavior with?

Comment: Are you calling Wait or Result anywhere?

Comment: Stephen Cleary's blog post may help: [Don't Block on Async Code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Comment: @StephenCleary, yes this is the exact code I can repro this issue in my project. Thanks!

Comment: @usr, no I  did not call `Wait` or `Result`. Thanks!

Comment: @Herne: You are compiling against .NET 4.5 **and** have `httpRuntime@targetPlatform` set to `4.5` in your `web.config`, right?

Comment: @StephenCleary, yes the project is currently using .Net 4.5 and it is correctly configured. Other DelegatingHandlers in the project works correctly but none of them does what I do here.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I had to do. I had to `ConfigureAwait(false)` to the call.

```
 var response = await this.ExecuteAsync1(() =>
            {
                return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            }).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: If that's really the solution, then you should raise this as a bug on Microsoft Connect.